# Trello - Can I change the color of cards or lists?

Tags: trello

I don't like the white cards on the light grey lists. I would like a way to make them stand out more. The lables just put a small strip of color. Can I change the color of the cards, the lists or even the text?

Comment: Card covers may be an alternative - have you tried them?

Comment: [New! Full Trello Card Covers And Colors Are Here](https://blog.trello.com/card-covers-and-colors "New! Full Trello Card Covers And Colors Are Here")

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately not, coloured backgrounds are currently under consideration as a new feature on the Trello development board, go to [Trello dev board](https://trello.com/dev) and place you vote.

Comment: I can't find this on the board anywhere. If it's really there, maybe somebody can post a link to the specific card? Otherwise, feel free to suggest it [here](http://help.trello.com/customer/portal/articles/990807-submitting-feature-requests-for-trello).

Answer (score 1):

'Card Colors for Trello' is a Chrome extension which colours a card when you add a label and works well. 
(Would also like to be able to change the colours of list backgrounds, or make transparent...).

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/card-colors-for-trello/nodlpencjjlohojddhflnahnfpfanbjm

Comment: Would you please link to that extension and maybe show a working example of it to improve your answer?

Comment: How does the extension work? If they can make an extension, we should be able to code something ourselves, right? I've seen several plugins that do this, how can we code it ourselves?